# Secondary display background not updating when using Twinview and Compiz

Tags: 10.10, compiz, 64-bit, twinview

My secondary monitor stopped updating the desktop background on my Maverick after an update I ran on January 10th. My desktop looks like this:

[image]

If I disable Compiz, the problem goes away. I've tried resetting the Compiz settings to defaults. What I haven't tried is a clean reinstall, but that I would obviously use as the last resort.

I'm running a 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10 with a Geforce 8600 as the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try from a terminal to:

```
compiz --replace
```

can you post your xorg file output? I have the exact same setup with a GeForce 8400 GS.
I guess you have installed Nvidia Xserver.

Comment: compiz --replace didn't fix it. Here's the xorg config file: http://pastebin.com/ad0U90iM

Comment: @Ville Sundberg I am at work right know, but I will reply to you in the evening with a copy or a diff of my XORG file so we can figure out whats going on.

Comment: @Ville Sundberg here is mine http://pastebin.com/JudVYqm9, which is working, didn't have time to check it thoroughly.

Comment: I've tried your xorg.conf and the effect persists, so the conf file itself probably isn't the culprit. I'll keep looking.